# Save content of variable to a file

Tags: javascript, jquery, 4d-database

Is it possible to save the content of a variable to a file with JQuery.

I have a html form (letter) which is saved and edited later on again by the user.
I capture the whole html document in a variable, but now I want to write that variable to a file and use a cron to save it back to the DB.

here is my code thus far

> ```
> $( document ).ready(function() {
>     var isDirty = false;
>     $("textarea").on("change", function() {
>         isDirty = (this.defaultValue !== this.value);
>         if (isDirty)
>             this.defaultValue = this.value;
>     });
>
>     $("input").on("change", function() {
>         isDirty = (this.defaultValue !== this.value);
>         if (isDirty)
>             this.defaultValue = this.value;
>     });
> });
>
> function getPageHTML() {
>     var vDocText = "<html>" + $("html").html() + "</html>";
>     console.log(vDocText);
> }
> ```

So I want to end up saving the content of `vDocText` to a file and send the file back to 4D (my database) with a php cron process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery is a JavaScript library and JavaScript is a client-side language, so you cannot save any data to files with it. Either you pass your data to a PHP script that stores the content on the server (e.g. in a database) or you save the data on the client (e.g. in a Cookie or using the [Web Storage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API)).

So, to answer your question: No, it is not possible to save the content of a variable to a file with jQuery.

However, there are [certain plugins](http://jquery.tiddlywiki.org/twFile.html) that provide access to the local file system through jQuery, but I would not recommend using them. By design, JavaScript does not have access to the local file system (for security reasons). The aforementioned plugin uses a couple of *hacks* and workarounds to access the file system (ActiveX and Java applets).

The best alternative, in my opinion, would be to issue an [AJAX request with jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) and have a PHP script on the server take care of writing (and further processing) the file.

Comment: Thanks, noted and will do so.